# Android - ListItem id changing when removing rows from ListView via ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, list, listview, android-arrayadapter

Fairly new to Android development and I've got a question.

I've got a ListView with TextViews. I've got an ArrayAdapter and I'm removing a ListItem on a buttonclick. In my ListActivity I am assigning ids to ListItems, the problem is that when I remove a ListItem the following ListItem inherits its id.

**i.e:**

Let's say that I have *2 ListItems*: *ListItem0* with id *0*, *ListItem 1* with id *1*. ==> If I delete *ListItem0* then *ListItem1* will get id *0*

Basically is there any way to *keep* ListItem ids even though I delete some of them?

**LATER EDIT:** Solved by removing the id from idList:

> idList.remove(position)

```
public void displayL() {
         Cursor c = mDbAdapter.fetchAllReminders();
         numberList.clear();
         idList.clear();
         startManagingCursor(c);
          c.moveToFirst();
          if (c .moveToFirst()) {
                while (c.isAfterLast() == false) {
                    id= c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(RemindersDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID));
                    String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(RemindersDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE));
                      numberList.add(name);
                      idList.add(id);
                    c.moveToNext();
                }
            }

        adapter = new ItemAdapter(this, R.layout.row, numberList, idList);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Adapter class:

```
public class ItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>  {
private   ArrayList<String> idList = null;
private ArrayList<String> numberList;
private ImageView delete_entry;
public RemindersDbAdapter mDbAdapter;
public View v;
public  ArrayList<String> clickId;
private long positionId;


public ItemAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<String> numberList,
               ArrayList<String> clickPosition) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, numberList);
    this.numberList = numberList;
    clickId = clickPosition;
}

@Override
    public int getPosition(String item) {
    return super.getPosition(item);
}

@Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
    return super.getItemId(position);
}

public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    v = convertView;
    if (v == null) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
}

mDbAdapter= new RemindersDbAdapter(v.getContext());
final String number = numberList.get(position);
mDbAdapter.open();

if (number != null) {
    final TextView tt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text_number);
    tt.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
    delete_entry = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.delete_entry);
    tt.setText(number);
    delete_entry.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            positionId = Integer.parseInt(clickId.get(position));

            if(position>=0) {
                Log.d("Delete--", "DELETING ID #" + positionId);
                Boolean b =  mDbAdapter.deleteReminder(positionId); //delete from database
                numberList.remove(number); //remove listItem
                notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
            mDbAdapter.close();
        }
    });
}
return v;
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look like you're removing the id from the idList when you remove the number from the numberList, so it looks like it's being inherited.  Try this.

```
    public void onClick(View v) {
        positionId = Integer.parseInt(clickId.get(position));

        if(position>=0) {
            Log.d("Delete--", "DELETING ID #" + positionId);
            Boolean b =  mDbAdapter.deleteReminder(positionId); //delete from database
            numberList.remove(number); //remove listItem
            idList.remove(position);
            notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
        mDbAdapter.close();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it was so obvious. I solved it by idList.remove(position);

Comment: Good call, position, not number.  Edited the answer.